# If $d\mid nm$ and $\gcd(n, m)= 1$ then exist $d_1, \,d_2$ such that $d=d_1d_2$ and $d_1\mid n,\,d_2\mid m$ (without Fund. Theorem of Arit)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We want to prove that if $d\mid nm$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$ then $d=d_1d_2$ where $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid m$ and $\gcd(d_1,d_2)=1$

We already proved it using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmethic. But we wonder if there is a way to prove it using only GCD basic theorems.

Our hints

If $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid m$, then $d_1d_2\mid nm$

$(a\mid b \implies a\mid bc)$

If $d\mid nm$ then $d\mid \gcd(d,n) \gcd(d,m)$ (Properties)

$\gcd(d_1,d_2)\mid \gcd(n,m)$

Comment: $d_1 = \gcd(n,d)$?

Comment: But it's only said that $n, m$ are co-prime !

Comment: Oh.. I see...You must be right......

Comment: There are other algebraic structures that have non-unique prime decompositions, so some very specific properties of $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$ must be used.

Comment: @OheyavHashim The answer below is not helpful? Note that it takes the same $d_1,d_2$ as I proposed ($n$ switched with $m$, but no other change)

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following two facts:

**Lemma 1:**

Given $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $gcd(m,n) = 1$, then there exists, $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $xm + yn = 1$

**Lemma 2:**

For, $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, if there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $xm + yn= 1$, then $gcd(m,n) = 1$.

**Proof:**

Now we can show that if $d_1 = gcd(d,n)$ and $d_2 = gcd(d,m)$ then,

$gcd(d_1, d_2) = 1$ and $d = d_1 d_2$.

The proof is trivial if $d_1 = 1$ or $d_2 = 1$. So, I will assume, $d_1 > 1$ and $d_2 > 2$.

$d_1 | m \implies \exists q_1 \in \mathbb{N} \ni m = q_1d_1$.

Similarly, $d_2 | n \implies \exists q_2 \in \mathbb{N} \ni n = q_2d_2$

From *Lemma-1*, there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
$$(xq_1)d_1 + (yq_2)d_2 = 1$$

Therefore it follows from *Lemma-2* that,
$$gcd(d_1, d_2) = 1$$

This implies $d = kd_1d_2$.

Now, it is given, $d | mn \implies kd_1d_2 | q_1q_2d_1d_2 \implies k | q_1q_2$.

Since $d_1 = gcd(d,m)$ and $d_2 = gcd(d,n)$, we have $gcd(k,q_1) = 1$ and $gcd(k,q_2) = 1$.

This taken together with $k | q_1q_2$ implies $k = 1$.

This proves that $d = d_1d_2$.

Comment: Why do you say gcd(d1,d2) implies d = kd1d2?

Comment: By our assumption, $d_1 | d$, therefore $d = md_1$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, $d_2 | d \implies d_2 | md_1$. Since $gcd(d_2, d_1) = 1$, $d_2 | m$, which implies, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \ni  m = kd_2$. This gives $d = kd_1d_2$.